# Given a random vector has univariate normal marginals, and a positive definite Covariance. Does this mean the vector is multivariate normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

So the question is basically in the title.

We know that if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ is multivariate normal for $\sigma$ positive definite, then we have that $X_i$ is normal. But is the converse statement true?

Say $X = (X_1, ..., X_n)$ with $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_{ii})$, $\sigma_{ij} = Cov(X_i, X_j)$ such that $\sigma$ is positive definite. Does that mean that $X$ is multivariate normal?

If we leave out the positive definite - condition, we can easily construct a counterexample, e.g. $X = -Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ but $X+Y \equiv 0$, so we have found a non trivial linear combination of $(X, Y)$ which is not normal.

I have looked quite a bit in the literature and couln't find a proof or counterexample.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a standard one-dimensional normal variable, and let $J$ be independent of $X$  with $$P(J=1)=2/3=1-P(J=-1)\,.$$ Define
$Y=XJ$. Then $X,Y$ are both $N(0,1)$ variables, and $$E(XY)=E(X^2)E(J)=1/3\,,$$
so the covariance matrix of $X,Y$ $$\frac23 I+ \frac13 (1,1)^T \cdot (1,1)$$ is positive definite.

However, $(X,Y)$ are certainly not jointly normal, since $P(X-Y=0)=2/3.$